# How to split LAN into two separate LANs using same internet connection

Tags: wifi, vlan, local-area-network, wlan

I have a router ZyXEL P-660HN-T3A and Switch ZyXEL GS1100-24 and I need to separate 2 ports on switch so clients connected to this ports can't see/access the others. I need the same thing to do with my wifi "from" zyxel p-660hn. Is VLANs the way to go? If so, I'm not sure if my hardware is capable of this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use 2 different VLANs. But unfortunately, the GS1100 is an unmanaged switch, so it doesn't support  that feature.

Comment: Thanks! So the option is to buy a new manageable switch or to buy another switch and use two of them?

Comment: Could someone advice me a good managed switch under $350 ? What about Netgear FS728TSEU ProSafe Fast or CISCO SRW224G4-K9-EU ?